# How is GitHub Action's name identified when the workflow is running?

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I published a GitHub Action with name **Marketly Incr Version** and with version as **v1.1**. When I referenced the action in yml as `uses: actions/Marketly-Incr-Version@v1.1` , I get the error below. I also tried lower case everything and still got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/actions/Marketly-Incr-Version/zipball/v1.1'. Error Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are referring to [this](https://github.com/gopala000/incr-version) action

The correct syntax is `owner/repo@ref`:

```
uses: gopala000/incr-version@v1.1
```

Btw if you click the green button on [the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/marketly-incr-version) page for this action, it gives you the syntax to use:

```
- name: Marketly Incr Version
  uses: gopala000/incr-version@v1.1
```

P.S. if you want to have your action follow the same versioning scheme as most actions in the marketplace, use [this](https://github.com/Actions-R-Us/actions-tagger) meta action to do that.

<sub>P.P.S I am the author</sub>